# Update multiple progress bars in 2 different loops

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I've got a windows program that is doing some updating to a database.  It has 2 loops which I'd like to show progress for.  The first loop gets a list of Customers and the second gets a list of Locations for that Customer:

```
DataTable dtCustomers = GetAllCustomers();

foreach(DataRow customer in dtCustomers.Rows)
{
    //update Customer Progressbar...

    //do some updating here...

    DataTable dtLocations = GetAllLocations(customer);

    foreach(DataRow location in dtLocations.Rows)
    {
        //do some updating here...

        //update Location Progressbar...
    }

    //reset Location Progressbar...
}
```

So what I'd like to do is show a visual progressbar (pb) of each loop.  The Customer pb would increment with each processed customer and so would the location pb...the only difference is the location pb would reset after each location, because it could take longer/shorter to update based on the location.

I started with 1 background worker and was able to update the customer pb just fine.  I put the following code in a "start" button:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    workerCustomers.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

and in the DoWork() event of the workerCustomer, I put the 2 loops.  I know that the location pb won't update because it would give the "Cross thread reference" error.  So how can I go about doing what I want?  I even tried to put 2 bg workers on the form and call one from the other, but again, another error stating the first worker is busy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you reporting progress you can pass additional userState object as second parameter (see [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) method defintion):

```
workerCustomers.ReportProgress(percentage1, percentage2);
```

And in `ProgressChanged` event handler you can update both progressBars:

```
void workerCustomers_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; // Customers
    progressBar2.Value = (int)e.UserState; // Locations
}
```

UPDATE: How you can use it in your case

```
DataTable dtCustomers = GetAllCustomers();
int customerIndex = 0;

foreach(DataRow customer in dtCustomers.Rows)
{
    //do some updating here...
    int customerPercentage = ++customerIndex * 100 / dtCustomers.Rows.Count;
    workerCustomers.ReportProgress(customerPercentage, 0);

    int locationIndex = 0;
    DataTable dtLocations = GetAllLocations(customer);

    foreach(DataRow location in dtLocations.Rows)
    {
        //do some updating here...
        int locationPecentage = ++locationIndex * 100 / dtLocations.Rows.Count;
        workerCustomers.ReportProgress(customerPercentage, locationPecentage);
    }

    workerCustomers.ReportProgress(customerPercentage, 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but it still doesn't update the 2nd progressbar for some reason.  I've updated my code with basic code (cut out all the fluff) to see if that would help but it didn't...see above...am I missing something?

Comment: @Robert I rolled back your update of question, because it changes the question. I've provided you way for passing two values from backgroundWorker, if you have another problem, than you should create another question.